# error undefined in this.state.places in react-native

Tags: react-native

I don't understand why the error should work normally this way, the error seems to be in scrowview but I don't understand why it happens, I have to write a lot because it says it has a lot of code but my problem is very simple so please ignore it that part and go to my code

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {  View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Home from './Mainpage'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

places:{
   maxHeight:200,
   marginHorizontal: 20,
   backgroundColor: '#fff'
 },
})
export default function Search({ navigation }) {
  state = {
  places: [
     {
       id: 1,
       title: 'Clinica da pele',
       description: 'Dermatologista',
       latitude:-2.42206406,
       longitude:-54.71947789,
     },
     {
       id: 2 ,
       title:'Unimed',
       description:'Hospital',
       latitude:-2.42501721,
       longitude:-54.71146077,
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       title: 'Dra. Josimar',
       description:'Dermatologista',
       latitude: -2.4288346,
       longitude:-54.7290553,
     }
   ]
 }

 return(


   <ScrollView>
      { this.state.places.map(place => (
       <View  key={place.id} style={styles.places}>
         <Text>{place.title}</Text>
         <Text>{place.description}</Text>
       </View>
     ))}
   
   </ScrollView>
 )
}
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use This binding in Functional Component. Remove this, and for state use React hook useState to add the state to the component. Check the code given below

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/bossy-truffles

Code:

```
import React, { PureComponent, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
// import Home from './Mainpage';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  places: {
    maxHeight: 200,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

export default ({ navigation }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    places: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Clinica da pele',
        description: 'Dermatologista',
        latitude: -2.42206406,
        longitude: -54.71947789,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Unimed',
        description: 'Hospital',
        latitude: -2.42501721,
        longitude: -54.71146077,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Dra. Josimar',
        description: 'Dermatologista',
        latitude: -2.4288346,
        longitude: -54.7290553,
      },
    ],
  });

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {state.places.map((place) => (
        <View key={place.id} style={styles.places}>
          <Text>{place.title}</Text>
          <Text>{place.description}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks man, but can you put information for each place in different boxes?

Comment: @Paulo Avila I didn't got your question can you specify little more...

Comment: its because like this all the information is in a same container, there is a way to each of this places in the state.places  have its container ?